# How to determine the smallest N such that there are X (or more) prime numbers with exactly N bits?

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, integer-programming

I understand how I can use the prime number theorem to determine how many primes exist for a given bit length: $\pi(2^n)-\pi(2^{n-1})$.

However, my specific problem is that I need to approach this in the exact opposite direction. Say I have a number of objects, and each object in the set of size $x$ is mapped to (identified by) a prime number. There may be multiple instances of each object, but there are $x$ unique types of objects (for example, if I have several each of apples and bananas, $x=2$; adding more apples or bananas will not increase $x$, but adding an orange means now $x=3$). Each prime number must be unique, as it is used to uniquely identify the type of object, and each prime must have *exactly* the same number of bits. This means, naturally, that I can't just choose the first $x$ prime numbers, as they will differ in bit length.

Lastly, I will be performing arithmetic on these numbers such that space becomes a concern, even just in theory. Assume that the $x$ is known ahead of time and will not change until the next time I run the program, so it is not necessary to have extra primes, so $\pi(2^n)-\pi(2^{n-1}) = x$ is perfectly acceptable. We don't need to worry about adding more, only that we have enough in the first place, in as little space as possible.

Therefore, I ultimately need to find the **smallest possible** $n$ such that $\pi(2^n)-\pi(2^{n-1}) \geq x$ (or at least the smallest possible $n$ such that that can be assumed to be true within some level of confidence, if it is unfeasible to be completely sure) given an arbitrary $x$. Just one final note: $x$ is likely to be small, in most cases $5 \leq x \leq 30$. However, this would ideally be scalable, which is why I want to figure this out algorithmically rather than storing and referencing precalculated data.

Comment: With so small $x$, you're talking about nine or ten bits maximum, and then you can just sieve and count primes to find the minimal required bit-length. That'll take milliseconds with non-optimised code. I don't see how space would be a concern there, however. Even using 32 or 64 bit integers you'd need a huge lot of data to store to get into a region where space might become a problem. If you use 16 bit integers for storage you have plenty of room for larger $x$, and you need an even huger lot of data before you need to worry about space.

Comment: @DanielFischer I need to worry about size because the primes will be multiplied and exponentiated many times while keeping the product < some large prime $p$. I need to maximize the number of operations I can do before hitting that limit without increasing $p$ and the best way to do that is to make sure I am using the smallest possible $x$ primes. Storage is not an issue as I am using an arbitrary-precision integer type. It's an issue because of the hard limit of $p$.

Comment: I see. I don't see yet why they all must have the same bit-length, but I assume you have a reason for that. Anyway, as I said, it's quick to sieve and count for such small $x$. That way, you also have the primes to use.